# Removing Duplicate Objects that contain different variables

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, duplicates

I have two objects that have the same name but contain different ages(values), I tried adding these objects to a map to remove duplicates but it won't remove. This is the model code I am testing:

```
two ab = new two("john", "20");
two ac = new two("chan", "30");
two ad = new two("john", "34");

ArrayList<two> ae = new ArrayList<>();

public void adding(){
ae.add(ab);
ae.add(ac);
ae.add(ad);
System.out.println(ae);
}

public void removeDuplicate(){
    Set<two> lhs = new HashSet<>();
    lhs.addAll(ae);
    ae.clear();
    ae.addAll(lhs);
    System.out.println(ae);
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    one five = new one();

    five.adding();
    five.removeDuplicate();
}
```

This is the class that is used for object type:

```
package teeestserrr;

public class two {

private String name;
private String age;

public two(String name, String age){
    this.age = age;
    this.name =  name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getAge(){
    return age;
}

public String toString(){
    return name + " " + age;
 }
}
```

Results are :

```
[john, chan, john]
[chan, john, john]
```

I also tried to make the `toString` return only name but the map used to remove duplicates doesn't seem to work even in that case. I don't understand and I cannot identify the underlying problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to override `equals` and `hashCode` in class `two`

Comment: Eran is correct. HashSet relies on those two methods for its operation (hence the name HashSet). Use your favourite search engine to find guidance on how those two methods should be implemented. It may even be that your IDE can generate them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override `equals` and `hashcode` method in `two`.
Equals should give result according to only `name` field and also hashcode should be formed using only `name` field, that will help you to achieve your aim.

```
package teeestserrr;

public class two {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public two(String name, String age){
        this.age = age;
        this.name =  name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge(){
        return age;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj==null)
            return false;
        if(name==null){
            return false;
        }
        if(!(obj instanceof two)){
            return false;
        }
        two another = (two)obj;
        return this.name.equals(another.name);
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return name==null?0:name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: why can i do the same method if I change the object type to String instead of object type two?

Comment: Your code `Set<two> lhs = new HashSet<>();`, uses hashset which works on the mechanism of hashing. And you have your custom object passed here, so you need to override `equals` and `hashcode` for your custom class.

Comment: @Vittal Kavitake is there another way to remove duplicates? I don't know how to override the equals and hash code :( Can you show me an example?

Comment: check the edited answer. added class two with equals and hashCode. Code is not compiled, so you can correct if any compilation issue.

Comment: Wow thats amazing, thanks. I wanted to know weather there was any other way to solve this problem. For example, if I were to do .getName() and store the names in a String array, then sort that . But the problem with this example, is the two objects are not linked to String objects. An suggestions ? :)

Comment: Simple. If they were not linked to string then you can use the property which they are linked to in equals and hashcode.

Comment: Can I use the method hashCode and equals in my 'one' class( the top of the page) instead of 'two'? if so, how would I go about this?

Comment: No, you cannot use it in one. Go through some tutorials for equals and hashCode to have better understanding about its concept. You can find one at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html